# labels created in Visual Studio 2015 TFS are not showing up for other users

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, label

I am attempting to create a label via Source Control Editor -> right click on repository project folder -> advanced -> apply label. The label creates perfectly, though the issue is I can not view the label list in the History tab under Labels on another user's machine.

I know the label creates in the repository as i can find it under get specific versions or compare using the label type dropdown under version for all users, however what i want is for the label to create and show for ALL users in the history Labels tab.

Can you please let me know the steps i need to take to create and post a label on the admin side of things to display for all in the History labels tab?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels can be seen for the users who have read permission to the scope (repository project folder in this case). If the user is not allowed to access the scope, then the label will be invisible. (see more on [scope](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/03/label-scope-revealed.html) here)

So, please make sure other users have the read permission for the repository project folder.

1. Select the project folder and Right-click on it under the collection in VS or web portal.
2. Choose **Advanced > Security**
3. Choose the Group/user for which you would like to set read permission
4. Set the **Read** permission to **Allow**

Comment: @Kevin Henzel, Any update for this issue? have you resolved it by above workaround?

Comment: It was actually a stupid issue... I was checking history one folder off of the chain in the tree which did not show history. This was a little confusing as the solution i was attempting to create a label for had a double nested folder structure in the solution. When i viewed history on the correct folder it was all there. Thanks!